# I'd like to know the difference of these two phrases. "have no choice but to" and "cannot be helped"

Tags: phrases

I'm not sure whether I can use these phrases interchangeably or not. One example is:

> Gas prices are getting higher and higher, but I have to fill up my car anyway, because I have to drive to work.

Another example:

> I got a job offer, but it was canceled, so I have to start job-hunting again.

In these cases, which is the most appropriate sentence to append to those examples?

> (a) "I have no choice" or
>   (b) "It cannot be helped" or
>   (c) "I cannot help it"

Is there is any difference in the usage between them, and, if so, could you explain it, please?

Comment: @tchrist  Thank you for the further editing. I just found out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use *I have no choice* to describe those situations. The phrase *I have no choice* means that you are in a difficult situation, but there is no practical alternative or option to do anything else, even if what you're doing isn't appealing.

On the other hand, *I can't help it* is something that we typically use to describe our own behavior or actions. For example:

> Beth: Stop coughing like that!
>   Seth: *I can't help it; I have something caught in my throat.*

The third phrase, *it cannot be helped*, is more impersonal, and is generally more likely to be used when describing a situation that doesn't involve a person's actions or choices, but simply describes the way things are:

> The fact that some English words are tricky to spell cannot be helped.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for the clear explanation.  It's very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

"(a) I have no choice" is the best in both cases. It refers to a personal act that is *voluntary* but chosen, usually reluctantly, in the face of certain restrictions.

"(b) It cannot be helped" refers to an act that is *impersonal* -- perhaps performed by another or a group -- as J.R. described, associated with some undesirable outcome, but still performed. Consider a politician during a war, "Yes the bombing will kill civilians, but it is necessary in order to hit the factories. It cannot be helped."

"(c ) I can't help it." This refers to an (allegedly) *involuntary* personal action. "I know I spit when I talk, but I make a lot of saliva. I can't help it!"